# Create TestProbe of an child actor from a name

Tags: akka, akka-persistence, akka-typed

Using akka typed: 2.6.10. My parent generates child actors to do some work as you can see below (note this is part of event sourced actor). Is there a way to acquire reference to internally created child actor using possibly name during testing time?

For example, below we have child actor `provider_1` which is created at initialization time and I am hoping to acquire a reference to TestProbe using this name from outside. I am reluctant to change the way code is structured for sake of testing, for example in [here](https://doc.akka.io//docs/akka/2.4/scala/testing.html#Using_Multiple_Probe_Actors) there are some reference to passing in ref/factory or re-constructing parent in test in order to test this, which I would like to avoid.

```
  def commandHandler(
    ctx: ActorContext[Command]
  ): (State, Command) => Effect[Event, State] = { (state, cmd) =>
    cmd match {
      case Init =>
         ctx.spawn(Provider(ctx.self), "provider_1")
        Effect.none
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `BehaviorTestKit` to test the actor, the actor gets run with an alternative `ActorContext` implementation.

So the following should work (note that `akka.actor.testkit.typed.Effect` has little relation to `Effect` in persistence), using scalatest matchers:

```
import akka.actor.testkit.typed.Effect.Spawned

val testKit = BehaviorTestKit(behaviorUnderTest)
testKit.run(Init)
val effect = testKit.retrieveEffect : akka.actor.testkit.typed.Effect
val childActorRef =
  effect match {
    case s: Spawned if s.childName == "provider_1" => s.ref
    case _ => fail()
  }
val childInbox = testKit.childInbox(childActorRef)
testKit.run(SendMessageToYourChild("hello"))
childInbox.hasMessages shouldBe true
childInbox.receiveMessage shouldBe MessageFromParent("hello")
```

`akka.actor.testkit.typed.scaladsl.TestInbox` is intended to be the synchronous behavior testing analogue to the asynchronous `TestProbe`.

I'm not aware of an analogous method for the asynchronous `ActorTestKit`, where a child actor will actually be spawned.